# issue on Node.js - the app hangs on 0.0.0.0:8080, not on localhost

Tags: jquery, node.js, file-upload, blueimp

I'm using BlueImp Fileuploader with Node.js back-end.
The app seems to run - output some test data with console.log, but when it doesn't seems to hang on the right IP.
http://d.pr/i/IqyW

Also it is complicated by the fact that I run Node.js through a Vagrant-VirtualBox Linux virtual machine (on Windows, I can't use pure Linux at the moment).

Would really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Can you post some of your code? Also, are you trying to access the VM using the localhost? Because to access the VM from Windows you should be using the IP that's assigned to the VM.

Comment: Tnx for reply, @AndrewLively. I am using this thing http://bit.ly/1541Hwh. I mentioned that I am using it through a Vagrant, which allows working on a Windows filesystem. The node.js itself (and Meteor.js which we actually run here) are on localhost:3000 and are accessible.